# python strange behavior of converting bytearray after making executable

Tags: python, hex, executable, cx-freeze

I have some project that works with rs232 protocol on raspberry pi. After all I make project executable using cx_freeze Executable and Cython build_ext. In the source I have bytearray like that

```
b = bytearray(b'\x1f\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00')
```

if I do

```
z = [x for x in b]
```

I'll get

```
[31, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

but when I make it executable and run the code on the same example I'm getting next

```
[44, 76, 76, 60, 76, 60, 76, 60, 60]
```

Why it works like that?

Comment: As an aside, `z = [x for x in b]` should *just be* `z = list(b)`.

Comment: Yes, I have a solution, but question is why it's work in that way? Thanks

Comment: It is impossible to say without a [mcve]